# Running a calendar on supervisor's page which is not editable by viewers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my web application, i have about 10K supervisors
On each supervisor's page, i would want to run a calendar built using PHP. 
The supervisors will be able to add/edit/delete their schedules in  each of the dates in the calendar.

Now there is another page where the users will get to view the profile page of all supervisors.
If supposing user B clicks on Supervisor X's profile page, B will get to see the schedules of X. User B can then go on to view another supervisor's profile.
The users are only allowed view access to the calendar.

Im not even sure where to begin this.

Any help on the steps i should take to approach? Pls also point me to the relevant tools that i should use for this.

My preferred languages for this project is php, ajax, jquery

Comment: Do you have PHP installed in your computer?

Comment: my web host company supports php

Comment: What do you know about web development?

Comment: i have done a few web sites, though it may be nothing compared to what the experts here can do.

Comment: I just want to know that Do you have basic idea about how to create simple CRUD application in php?

Comment: Years ago i did that using jsp to CRUD records into mysql, not with php though. I guess that shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64151/discussion-between-indrasinh-bihola-and-schenker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need 4 things:**

1) A calendar like so: [calendar](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-web-calendar-in-php)

2) Database like MySQL to store events and such

3) A login script that assigns session variables.

4) If login id doesn't match corresponding calendar id, user can't edit calendar

Thats pretty much it. You'll have to fill in the rest.